# Error Uploading JPEG to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, blob, jpeg

I am getting the error below when trying to upload an JPEG image to my MySQL database (Image is a BLOB):

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=57 (Image)  VALUES ('ÿØÿà\0JFIF\0\0\0\0\0\0ÿá\0XExif\0\0MM\0*\0\0\' at line 1
```

I would really appreciate if you could tell me the problem in my code.

```
$sql = sprintf(
"INSERT INTO recipies WHERE id=$id (Image) VALUES ('%s')", mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])));
$results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its insert into or update where.

You might want this:

```
$sql = sprintf(
"UPDATE recipies SET Image = '%s' WHERE id=$id", mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])));
$results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this would be more correct syntax

```
$sql = sprintf(
"INSERT INTO recipies (Image) VALUES ('%s') ", mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])));
$results = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

**EDIT**

It seems you're confused with SQL UPDATE syntax and MySQL particular mess. So correct syntax would be

```
INSERT
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
```

**Or**:

```
INSERT 
    [INTO] tbl_name
    SET col_name={expr | DEFAULT}, ...
```

So you friend is the [MySQL::INSERT Syntax Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html). 
Happy Querying!

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like you are trying to update rather than insert

```
UPDATE recipes SET Image= ('%s') WHERE id = %d
```